# Django MySQL query output error while passing parameters

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
cur=connection.cursor()

def fillDoctors(key_bodyloc,proportion):
    bodyloc_specialty_query="select distinct Speciality from body_speciality where body_location in (%s) "
    #cur.execute(bodyloc_specialty_query)
    data1=([key_bodyloc])
    #print(bodyloc_specialty_query,data)
    cur.execute(bodyloc_specialty_query,data1)
    results=cur.fetchall()
    specialities=[x[0] for x in results]
    condition=""
    for speciality in specialities:
        print(str(speciality))
        condition=condition+"'%"+speciality+"%'"+" or Speciality like "
    #print(speciality)
    #print(condition)
    specialty_doctors_query="select DoctorName,Speciality,ClinicName from Doctors where Speciality like %s limit %s"
    data2=([condition,proportion])
    print(specialty_doctors_query,data2)
    cur.execute(specialty_doctors_query,data2)

    final=cur.fetchall()
    print(final)
```

The line `final=cur.fetchall()` returns an empty tuple in each iteration. I've verified that the table Doctors isn't empty and the code works fine when the 'condition' is hard-coded. The code is supposed to print the doctor details for each speciality. Can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are not passing your `data1` into `bodyloc_specialty_query` properly when calling `cur.execute(bodyloc_specialty_query,data1)` and it causes the problem.

The syntax of string injection in Python is the following:

```
str1 = "some string %s" % "other string"
```

Instead of this way of adding a string to a string, use Pythons `format` builtin function:

```
str1 = "some string {str2}".format(str2="other_string").
```

But make sure that your `str2` is a string or convertable to string.

I can see your `data1` is a `list`, not `str`. You should convert it to `str` first. Good luck.

Comment: There is literally no difference between `%` and `format` when it comes to security from SQL injection: neither offers any at all.

Comment: Ok. Edited. I think I need to make a research on that

Comment: The line results=cur.fetchall() works fine and returns the expected results. The problem is with the 'specialty_doctors_query' is what I know, but I am not able to understand what though.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of passing in parameters to the execute method is that they get escaped. So, your condition is treated as a single string, rather than a series of parameters joined by SQL. Also, you can't use a parameter for the LIMIT value.

You need to build up some SQL and placeholders by interpolation, then just pass the values.

```
like = "speciality LIKE %%%s%%"
condition = like + (" OR {}".format(like)) * len(specialities)
query = "select DoctorName,Speciality,ClinicName from Doctors where {} LIMIT {}".format(condition, proportion)
cursor.execute(query, specialities)
```

for speciality in specialities:
    condition=condition+"'%"+speciality+"%'"+" or Speciality like "